# Issue when reprojecting shapefile using OSGEO in Python: prj file missing and kernel restart

Tags: python, coordinate-system, gdal, ogr, osgeo

I tried to reproject a shapefile based on the projection of a raster file following [this example](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/projection.html) (section "Reproject a Layer").

My code is as follows:

```
    # open the raster tif and extract crs
    t = "path/to/raster.tif"
    tif = gdal.Open(t)
    crs1 = tif.GetSpatialRef()#.GetProjection()
    tif = None
    # open shapefile
    drv = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
    s = "path/to/shapefile.shp"
    # set name of the new shapefile
    sUTM = "shapefile_UTM.shp"
    LayerName = "shapefile_UTM"
    if os.path.exists(sUTM):
        drv.DeleteDataSource(sUTM)
    shp = drv.Open(s)
    layer = shp.GetLayer()
    crs0 = layer.GetSpatialRef()
    # transformation from crs0 to crs1
    coordTrans = osr.CoordinateTransformation(crs0, crs1)
    # create output shapefile
    outSHP = drv.CreateDataSource(sUTM)
    outLayer = outSHP.CreateLayer(LayerName,
                                  geom_type = ogr.wkbMultiPolygon)
    lyrdef = layer.GetLayerDefn()
    for i in range(0, lyrdef.GetFieldCount()):
        fieldDefn = lyrdef.GetFieldDefn(i)
        outLayer.CreateField(fieldDefn)
    outdef = outLayer.GetLayerDefn()
    feature = layer.GetNextFeature()
    while feature:
        geom = feature.GetGeometryRef()
        geom.Transform(coordTrans)
        outFeature = ogr.Feature(outdef)
        outFeature.SetGeometry(geom)
        for i in range(0, outdef.GetFieldCount()):
            outFeature.SetField(outdef.GetFieldDefn(i).GetNameRef(),
                                feature.GetField(i))
        outLayer.CreateFeature(outFeature)
        outFeature = None
        feature = layer.GetNextFeature()
    layer = None
    shp = None
    outSHP = None
```

However, when I run this code, it seems to run into some issues, because it ends with `Restarting kernel...`  and all variables are gone.

Moreover, the output shapefile has only `.dbf`, `.shp` and `.shx` files. There is no `.prj` file. Of course, I could write this file in an additional step, but I think there is some underlying issue somewhere which I would prefer to resolve instead of fixing the outcome.

What is the error in the above shown code?

**Edit:**

The reference system I want to transform the shapefile to—i.e., what `print(crs1)` gives—is:

```
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 35S",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",27],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",10000000],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["Easting",EAST],
    AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","32735"]]
```

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify the CRS of the raster. It may not be supported.

Comment: @Vince I want to have the Shapefile in UTM zone 35S. I added the full info that was stored in the ```crs1``` variable to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can greatly simplify the operation using `gdal.VectorTranslate`

```py
from osgeo import gdal

# Open the raster tif and extract crs
t = "path/to/raster.tif"
tif = gdal.Open(t)
crs1 = tif.GetProjectionRef()
tif = None

# Input shp path
s = "path/to/shapefile.shp"

# Set name of the new shapefile
sUTM = "shapefile_UTM.shp"
if os.path.exists(sUTM):
    drv.DeleteDataSource(sUTM)

# Open shp input, set destination crs output to
# raster crs and write to output shp name
srcDS = gdal.OpenEx(s)
ds = gdal.VectorTranslate(sUTM, srcDS, format='ESRI Shapefile', dstSRS=crs1, reproject=True)

ds = None
srcDS = None

# Write prj
with open(f"{os.path.splitext(sUTM)[0]}.prj", 'w') as f:
    f.write(crs1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solved the problem and additionally, made the script shorter and easier to comprehend. I wonder why they have this cumbersome example on the Python GDAL/OGR Cookbook documentation. Perhaps it is outdated.

Comment: Exactly. Although most parts of the website from your sample remain relevant, it has been published on a code repository not updated since 5 years https://github.com/pcjericks/py-gdalogr-cookbook/ and for most content since 7/8 years